# Declaration of pointers in c

Tags: c, char, int

I am using gcc 4.8.1 and I am unable to understand output of following program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

    char* a, b, c;
    int* d, e, f;
    float* g, h, i;
    printf("Size of a %zu and b %zu and c %zu \n", sizeof(a), sizeof(b), sizeof(c));
    printf("Size of d %zu and e %zu and f %zu and int is %zu \n", sizeof(d), sizeof(e), sizeof(f), sizeof(int*));
    printf("Size of g %zu and h %zu and i %zu and float is %zu \n", sizeof(g), sizeof(h), sizeof(i), sizeof(float));
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output is

```
Size of a 4 and b 1 and c 1
Size of d 4 and e 4 and f 4 and int is 4
Size of g 4 and h 4 and i 4 and float is 4
```

My question is why `b` and `c` are not `char*` type whereas same is possible in case of `int` and `float`. I want to know about how C grammar splits declarations.

Comment: In you code, you print the `sizeof(int *)` when you claim to be printing the `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Hi Bill, that I understand and did it intentionally to check size of pointer. Please stick to main topic why a is of char* type where as b and c are char type.

Comment: to answer the why, you need to check the size of a pointer in your platform. I believe it is same as the size of an int or that of a float.

Comment: I'm not sure, what's your question. Is it why `char* a, b;` does not declare two pointers, or is it why `int* d, e;` does declare two pointers (what it also doesn't, although their sizes may suggest that)?

Comment: mafso my question is  why char* a, b; does not declare two pointers,

Answer (score 6):

In a declaration like

```
char* a, b, c;
```

Only the type `char` is used for all variables, not whether it is a pointer (`*` symbol). When used like that this (equivalent) syntax makes it more clear:

```
char *a, b, c;
```

To define 3 pointers:

```
char *a, *b, *c;
```

Or in cases where multiple pointers to char are often used, maybe do a typedef:

```
typedef char* char_buffer;
char_buffer a, b, c;
```

Comment: Answer is not clear my question is why? not what should I do to make it correct. I just want to know some properties of comma operator or something else which I am not aware of

Comment: @user1492793 That's how declaration syntax in C works. That's what the standard says. The design decision behind this is, that you might want to declare pointers and values at the same time, so you can choose.

Comment: Please elaborate the design decision a bit more , currently I am unable to understand.

Comment: I'm not sure about why it is like that, possibly it has some advantages in earlier programming styles (before object oriented).
It also applies for other kinds of declarations, for example `char (*a)(int, int), (*b)(void);` declares a as a pointer to a function returning a `char` and taking two `int` arguments, and `b` as a pointer to a function returning a `char` and taking no arguments.
And it gets even more complicated with the array declaration syntax `[]`...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using a bad style of declarations

These declarations

```
char* a, b, c;
int* d, e, f;
float* g, h, i;
```

are equivalent to

```
char* a;
char b, c;
int* d;
int e, f;
float* g;
float  h, i;
```

`sizeof` an object of type `char` is equal to `1` while `sizeof( char * )` in your system is equal to 4. So you get correct output

```
Size of a 4 and b 1 and c 1
```

As `sizeof( int )` and `sizeof( float )` in your system is equal to `4` then you get output

```
Size of d 4 and e 4 and f 4 and int is 4
Size of g 4 and h 4 and i 4 and float is 4
```

I said that you use bad style of programming because the declarations you are using like this

```
char* a, b, c;
```

do not consistent with the C grammar. The C grammar splits declarations in declaration specifiers (for the statement above it is keyword `char`) and declarators (in statement above they are `*a`, `b`, and `c` ). So you should follow the C grammar. In this case your code will be more clear.

```
char *a, b, c;
```

(Compare for example

```
char unsigned* c;
```

and

```
char unsigned *c;
```

What declaration is more clear?)

Do not forget that your code can read programmers that for example do not know C but know C#. In this case they will be simply confused. They will consider the declarations in the wrong way as you considered them in your post.

Answer (score 1):

`char* a, b, c;`

here, `a` is of type `char *`, `b` and `c` are of type `char`. same goes for others also.

It is the case in your platform, `int` and `float` takes 4 bytes, just as a size of pointer [means `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(float)` is same as `sizeof(int *)` and `sizeof(float *)` , respectively] whereas, `char` is of size 1.

So, your `sizeof(a)` yields 4 [`a` being a pointer], when `sizeof(b)` gives 1 [`b` is of type `char`].

- Don't be under the impression that `e`, `f` are `int*`. They are not.
- Don't be under the impression that `h`, `i` are `float *`. Again,
  they are not.

Answer (score 1):

The only pointers in your program are `a`, `d`, and `g`.

It just happens that on your platform that `int *`, `float *`, `int`, and `float` all have the same size.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* a, b, c;
```

`*a` is a char (when `a` itself is valid)
`b` is a char
`c` is a char

Answer (score 1):

[too long for a comment]

Just for completeness: To define three `char` pointers (instead of one `char` pointer and two `char`s) I'd go for:

```
char * a; /* This is used to do ... */
char * b; /* This is used to do ... */
char * c; /* This is used to do ... */
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a separate asterisk `*` for every pointer you want to delare (because the language grammar says so):

```
// declare 3 pointers
char *a, *b, *c;
```

To make this clearer (to myself) I prefer to put the asterisk directly before the variable name, and not directly after the type specifier.

```
// I prefer this:
char *d;
// instead of this:
char* e;
```

This does not become apparant with `int` and `float` on your machine because these happen to have the same size as their respective pointer types (4).